# Generate XML using server side suiteScript 2.0

Tags: xml, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to use suitescript on a 2.0 Suitelet script to generate xml and then I would like to return the Xml as a string.     Please note, that I have to build this XML on the fly so I can't just read it from a file.     On a client script I can use native javascript and build around the document but in the server side I assume I have to use the N/XML module and leverage Document, Element, and Node to build this.
An example of the XML I would like to return as a string might be generated as the following:

As a side note, I was hoping I would not do this directly as a string but rather work with the xml logic by not just building a long string and parsing that string to XML.

```
<shipment>
    <book>
        <title>aaa</title>
        <author>bbb</author>            
    </book>
</shipment>
```

In the end I want to return string:

```
"<shipment><book><title>aaa</title><author>bbb></author></book></shipment>"
```

As I said I assume since its a server side suitescript I would use N/xml and its document,node,parser, etc.   members..

the code I have is as follows:

```
require(["N/xml"]);
var x= require("N/xml");
var xmlDocument = x.Parser.fromString({
                text: '<shipment/>'
            });
var newBookNode = xmlDocument.createElement("book"); 
    var newTitleNode = xmlDocument.createElement("title"); 
    var newTitleNodeValue = xmlDocument.createTextNode("aaa"); 
    var newAuthorNode = xmlDocument.createElement("author"); 
    var newAuthorNodeValue = xmlDocument.createTextNode("bbbb");

    newBookNode.appendChild(newTitleNode);
    newBookNode.appendChild(newAuthorNode);    
    newTitleNode.appendChild(newTitleNodeValue);
    newAuthorNode.appendChild(newAuthorNodeValue);

   xmlDocument.appendChild(newBookNode)
   var asString2 = x.Parser.toString({document:doc1})
```

But the line that does the appendChild gives me an error "HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.: null"

Comment: To clarify, the return string should simply be the xml that is generated only as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed. You can use N/xml as follows:

```js
require(['N/xml'...], function(xml,...){

   var doc = xml.Parser.fromString({
      text:'<cXML payloadID="'+ payLoadId +'"></cXML>'
   });

   doc.documentElement.appendChild({newChild:doc.createElement({tagName:'Lab'})});

   var asString = xml.Parser.toString({document:doc});


});
```

Comment: I tried following your code as provided.   I did not have a payloadID so I just made that '123'.    When i ran the appendChild on it I got an error that     "Error: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.\n      I will update my question to indicate your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I had tried simplifying some live code to use as an example but went too far. Edited the example.

Comment: That was the issue... the .documentElement was what I was missing the whole time.  That worked great.